# type 'Future<PickedFile?>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<File>' , error after migrating to null safety

Tags: android, ios, flutter, imagepicker

I have recently migrated my flutter app to null safety 2.12.0 , I had to do a lot of changes to my code and I'm only stuck at my image picker and upload functions. I manage to change the null accepted variables. application runs without an issue but after image has been picked its not shown in the ui or go down for other pipe line functions that requires the image file data. I pretty new to flutter and this sudden changes to flutter caused much confusion. I would much appreciate the solution for this and a good explanation of avoiding such problems in the future, thank you !

Git of entire code "https://github.com/sudaraka93/stack.git"

```
  late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  late Size deviceSize;
  Future<File>? file;
  late String base64Image;
  String status = '';
  late File tmpFile;
  String errMessage = 'Error Uploading Image';
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  final TextEditingController CommentController = new TextEditingController();


  @override
  void initState() {
  }

  chooseImage() {
    setState((){
      file =  ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery) as Future<File>;
    });
  }

  startUpload()async {
    setStatus('Uploading Image...');
    if (null == tmpFile) {
      setStatus(errMessage);
      return;
    }
    String fileName = tmpFile.path.split('/').last;
    upload(base64Image);
  }
  Widget showImage() {
    return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: file,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            null != snapshot.data) {
          tmpFile = snapshot.data!;
          base64Image = base64Encode(snapshot.data!.readAsBytesSync());
          return Flexible(
              child:Container(
                child:Image.file(
                  snapshot.data!,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              )
          );
        } else if (null != snapshot.error) {
          return const Text(
            '画像の選択エラー',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        } else {
          return const Text(
            '画像が選択されていません',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImagePicker` is no longer using `File` as a data type, Instead you have to use `PickedFile`

Just change

```
Future<File>? file
```

to

```
Future<PickedFile>? file
```

change data type of `tmpFile` to `PickedFile`. Convert to base64 like this

```
base64Image = base64Encode(File(snapshot.data.path).readAsBytesSync());
```

and then for show image use wedge like this

```
Image.file(File(snapshot.data.path))
```

Comment: I'm getting issues with  Widget showImage() . after I change the all its accepting parameters to pickedFile.  do I need to convert it to a file and do I need to change the method where I convert it to base64

Comment: type 'Future<PickedFile?>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<PickedFile>?' in type cast I'm getting this when I run it

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look.